# proof verification -- $A, B, C$ mutually independent events $\rightarrow A, B \cap C^C$ independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, elementary-set-theory

Keep in mind the proof is for a first class in probability theory!

\begin{align*}
    P(A \cap (B \cup C^C)) &= P((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C^c)) \\
&= P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap C^c) - P(A \cap B \cap C^c) \\
&= P(A)(P(B) + P(C^c)) - P(A)P(B|A)P(C^c|B \cap A)) \\
&= P(A)(P(B) + P(C^c)) - P(A)P(B)P(C^c) \\
            &= P(A) (P(B) + P(C^c) -P(B)P(C^c)) \\
            &= P(A)(P(B \cup C^c))
\end{align*}

so they are independent.

Comment: You are assuming that $C^{c}$ and $B \cap A$ are independent. I think this needs a proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy good point. Thanks!